# my bootstrap carousel fdi-Carousel slide not sliding at all

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

when in check for any error in console for chrome `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`i get to see this error code in my code .
what might be the problem with my code any help is welcome. this is my code .this slider_flow.php .this is the link to the website [link](http://testmail.haoyetu.com)

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span12">
                <div class="well">
                    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel fdi-Carousel slide">
                     <!-- Carousel items -->
                        <div class="carousel fdi-Carousel slide" id="eventCarousel" data-interval="0">
                            <div class="carousel-inner onebyone-carosel">
                                <div class="item active">
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" class="img-responsive center-block"></a>
                                        <div class="text-center">1</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item">
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" class="img-responsive center-block"></a>
                                        <div class="text-center">2</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item">
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" class="img-responsive center-block"></a>
                                        <div class="text-center">3</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item">
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" class="img-responsive center-block"></a>
                                        <div class="text-center">4</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item">
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" class="img-responsive center-block"></a>
                                        <div class="text-center">5</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item">
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" class="img-responsive center-block"></a>
                                        <div class="text-center">6</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item">
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" class="img-responsive center-block"></a>
                                        <div class="text-center">7</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#eventCarousel" data-slide="prev"></a>
                            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#eventCarousel" data-slide="next"></a>
                        </div>
                        <!--/carousel-inner-->
                    </div><!--/myCarousel-->
                </div><!--/well-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

this my slider_flow.css

```
    .carousel-inner.onebyone-carosel { margin: auto; width: 90%; }
    .onebyone-carosel .active.left { left: -25.00%; }
    .onebyone-carosel .active.right { left: 25.00%; }
    .onebyone-carosel .next { left: 25.00%; }
    .onebyone-carosel .prev { left: -25.00%; }
```

this my slider_flow.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.fdi-Carousel .item').each(function () {
        var next = $(this).next();
        if (!next.length) {
            next = $(this).siblings(':first');
        }
        next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

        var next2 = next.next();
        if (!next2.length) {
            next2 = $(this).siblings(':first');
        }
        next2.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

        var next3 = next2.next();
        if(!next3.length){
            next3 = $(this).siblings(':first');
        }
        next3.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
    });
});
```

this where all js scripts are linked to the whole website.footer.php

```
<div class="footer-section">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="footer-top">
                                <div class="social-icons">
                                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/WandaSokoLtd/"><i class="icon1"></i></a>
                                        <a href="https://twitter.com/WandaSokoLtd"><i class="icon2"></i></a>
                                        <!--a href="#"><i class="icon3"></i></a-->
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                    <div class="footer-bottom">
                        <p> Copyright &copy;
                            <script>
                              var currentDate = new Date(),
                                  day = currentDate.getDate(),
                                  month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1,
                                  year = currentDate.getFullYear();
                              document.write(day + "/" + month + "/" + year)
                            </script> 
                            All rights  Reserved | by<a href="http://www.wandasoko.org/" target="target_blank">WandaSoko</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
            <a class="scroll" href="#home" id="toTop" style="display: block;"> <span id="toTopHover" style="opacity: 1;"> </span></a>

                </div>
            </div>
                    <!-- jQuery -->
        <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
        <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/responsiveslides.min.js"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        $(document).ready(function() {

                            $().UItoTop({ easingType: 'easeOutQuart' });

                        });
                    </script>
        <!-- script for menu -->                
         <script>
             $("label.menu").click(function(){
             $(".top-menu ul").slideToggle("slow" , function(){
             });
             });
         </script>
        <!-- //script for menu -->

        <!-- other useful jquery -->
        <script type="application/x-javascript"> addEventListener("load", function() { setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0); }, false); function hideURLbar(){ window.scrollTo(0,1); } </script>
        <script>
                $(function () {
                  $("#slider").responsiveSlides({
                    auto: true,
                    nav: true,
                    speed: 500,
                    namespace: "callbacks",
                    pager: true,
                  });
                });
        </script>

                      <!-- start-smoth-scrolling-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/move-top.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/easing.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                    $(".scroll").click(function(event){     
                        event.preventDefault();
                        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top},1200);
                    });
                });
            </script>
        <script src="assets/js/slider_flow.js"></script>
        <!--End-smoth-scrolling-->

            <script src="assets/js/jquery.swipebox.min.js"></script> 
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    jQuery(function($) {
                        $(".swipebox").swipebox();
                    });
                </script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                        $(document).ready(function() {
                        $('#myCarousel').carousel({
                        interval: 10000
                           })
                        });
                </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import jQuery before you can use it:

```html
<script src="assets/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> <!-- This must be before any jQuery use -->
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    
        $().UItoTop({ easingType: 'easeOutQuart' });
    
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Even after importing  it before all other jQuery script it is not working .

Comment: @harri looking at the code in your test environment the jQuery import is still at the same place. try moving line 249 (the import of jQuery) to line 25 (before first usage of jQuery)

Comment: i have updated the code on test environment with the JQuery  import at the correct environment and still i get the same error

Comment: @harri I still see no changes on the page (double-checked it with chrome & firefox). Are you sure you uploaded your edits correctly?

Comment: yah i have even updated the the question after making the changes check `footer.php `code on the question i imported the JQuery the way you told me to do it .

Comment: @harri replace the <head> section of your document with the html of [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/96vdkxkg/)

Comment: still nothing changes the slides have disappeared only have been left

Comment: @harri It seemed like the bootstrap javascript was missing. I added it to the [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/96vdkxkg/1/)

Comment: @harri You're welcome. I'm glad that I could solve your issue.